# Some question regarding the proof of Cantor normal form.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

So basically I wanted to prove Cantor normal form using transfinite induction. 
There is a good post here:

[How to prove that Cantor's normal form can produce all ordinal numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197868/how-to-prove-that-cantors-normal-form-can-produce-all-ordinal-numbers).

But I have some question regarding one part of the proof.

In that post, one part reads:

"Note that there is a greatest ordinal $\delta$ such that $\omega^\delta \leq \alpha$ (since the least ordinal $\zeta$ such that $\omega^\zeta > \alpha$ must be a successor ordinal)."

I have no intuition why this is true (Sorry if the statement is too obvious for some) meaning;

1.) Why such a lower bound exist in the first place

2.)why "least ordinal $\zeta$ such that $\omega^\zeta > \alpha$ must be a successor ordinal" (already answered)

hence I was hoping to get some explanation on that point.

Thank you, Cheers

Comment: I believe there are different ways to define operations on ordinal numbers. Please tell me how $\omega^\zeta$ is defined when $\zeta$ is a limit ordinal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the least ordinal $\zeta$ such that $\omega^\zeta>\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.  Since $\zeta$ is a limit ordinal, $\omega^\zeta$ is the supremum of all the ordinals $\omega^\delta$ for $\delta<\zeta$.  By minimality of $\zeta$, $\omega^\delta\leq\alpha$ for all $\delta<\zeta$.  But then $\omega^\zeta$ is also at most $\alpha$, since it is the least upper bound of the $\omega^\delta$ and $\alpha$ is an upper bound for them.  This is a contradiction.

Therefore, $\zeta$ is a successor ordinal, and $\zeta=\delta+1$ for some $\delta$.  This $\delta$ is then the greatest ordinal such that $\omega^\delta\leq\alpha$.

Comment: Ahh nice answer, but I must apologize for not making my question precise. Your answer solves half of my concern, the other (first-half) half is that why there is a greatest $\delta$. such that $\omega^{\delta} \leq \alpha$.

Comment: @some1fromhell: What is the least value that $\omega^{\alpha+1}$ could be?

Answer (score 0):

1) Why such a lower bound exist in the first place?

There must exist a bound $<\alpha+1$ because $\omega^{\alpha+1}>\alpha$.
And there must be a greatest bound because:

- If $\alpha$ can't be expressed in the form of $\omega^\beta$ you can "count backwards" until the previous power of $\omega$
- And if $α=\omega^\beta$ than $\delta=\beta$